# String from CSV to list - Python

Tags: list, python-2.7, csv

I don't get it. I have a CSV data with the following content:

```
wurst;ball;hoden;sack
1;2;3;4
4;3;2;1
```

I want to iterate over the CSV data and put the heads in one list and the content in another list. Heres my code so far:

```
data = [ i.strip() for i in open('test.csv', 'r').readlines() ]

for i_c, i in enumerate(data):
    if i_c == 0:
            heads = i
    else:
            content = i

heads.split(";")
content.split(";")
print heads
```

That always returns the following string, not a valid list.

```
wurst;ball;hoden;sack
```

Why does split not work on this string?

Greetings and merry Christmas,
Jan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `split` method returns the list, it does not modify the object in place.  Try:

```
heads = heads.split(";")
content = content.split(";")
```

I've noticed also that your data seems to all be integers.  You might consider instead the following for `content`:

```
content = [int(i) for i in content.split(";")]
```

The reason is that `split` returns a list of strings, and it seems like you might need to deal with them as numbers in your code later on.  Of course, disregard if you are expecting non-numeric data to show up at some point.

Comment: Grml, what an easy solution.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jwi I hope it helps - if so, please do the checky-mark thing.  I've also added an edit to the answer that might be relevant to your situation.